# Comparing two different text files and replacing similar words

Tags: java

I started learning Java recently and I need to compare 1000 words in a text file and a thesaurus text file. Each line in the thesaurus text file has words that are similar and contains one word each line from the 1000 words which are on one line each. Each word in the thesaurus is separated by a comma. I think I nearly have it. What I need to do i next is check if a word is contained in the thesaurus and if it is, map that line of words in the thesaurus to the the word in the 1000 words text file and im not sure how to do that.

```
package ie.gmit.sw;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Parser {
    private Map<String, String>map = new TreeMap<>();
    private Collection<String>google = new TreeSet<>(); 

    public void parseGoogle(String file) throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader brGoogle = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("google-1000.txt"));


        String word = null;

        while((word = brGoogle.readLine())!= null)
        {
            google.add(word);
        }

        brGoogle.close();


    }//parseGoogle

    public void parse(String file)throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader brMoby = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MobyThesaurus2.txt"));

        String line = null;

        while((line = brMoby.readLine())!= null)
        {
            String[] words = line.split(",");


        }


    }

    public String[] getGoogleWord(String[] words) {
        if(google.contains(words))
        {

        }
        return words;
    }



}//class Parser
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? "Brick wall" could mean many things.

Comment: Please provide more details about the task and your effort, as it is not quite clear which results you expect and what you have done to achieve them.  Cheers!

Comment: @AlexRudenko I have edited the question, hopefully it is more clear. Thanks

Comment: The word from the _Google_ may appear only in one line of the thesaurus, or multiple lines may contain it?  Why would you need to split the thesaurus lines into words?  You could just use `String`'s contains method to verify if a word occurs in a line.

Answer (score 0):

Example implementation of the mapper:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

  public Map<String, List<String>> mapWordsToThesaurus(Set<String> words, Set<String> thesaurus) {
    Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
    words.forEach(
        word ->
            result.put(
                word,
                thesaurus.stream()
                    .filter(line -> line.contains(word))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())));
    return result;
  }
```